# How to transpose groups of rows to columns

Tags: sql, pivot, postgresql-9.3, crosstab

i have the following table structure:

```
NAME    SUBJECT  LEVEL      RESULT
Smith   maths    beginner   C
Miller  maths    pro        B
Prince  maths    beginner   F
Smith   physics  pro        B
Miller  physics  pro        B
Prince  physics  beginner   E
```

And I want some kind of transposing, so that the result would look like this:

```
NAME    LEVEL_maths  RESULT_maths  LEVEL_physics   RESULT_physics
Smith   beginner     C             pro             B
Miller  pro          B             pro             B
...
```

Any idea how this can be done with (Postgre)SQL? Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select name, 
max(case when subject='maths' then level else end)level_maths,
max(case when subject='maths' then RESULT else end)RESULT_maths,
max(case when subject='physics' then level else end)level_physics,
max(case when subject='physics' then RESULT else end)RESULT_physics
from test
group by name;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bhavesh, that was fast. And exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @DeepanshuRathi it should as it follows ANSI SQL. I have not tested in MySQL though. let me know if it does not work.